# MongoDB: Error when saving DBObject with Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

Using:
mongo-java-driver-3.2.2.jar
and
morphia-1.1.1.jar

The code:

`for (UserList userList: userLists){
   DBObject userListDbObj = SingletonLaunchDB.getMorphia().toDBObject(userList);
   SingletonLaunchDB.getMongo().save(userListDbObj);
}`

Error trace:

`Grave:   java.lang.RuntimeException: Generic TypeVariable not supported!
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappedField.toClass(MappedField.java:616)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EphemeralMappedField.getSubClass(EphemeralMappedField.java:84)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EphemeralMappedField.<init>(EphemeralMappedField.java:39)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappedField.discoverType(MappedField.java:498)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappedField.discover(MappedField.java:465)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappedField.<init>(MappedField.java:93)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappedClass.discover(MappedClass.java:540)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappedClass.<init>(MappedClass.java:124)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.getMappedClass(Mapper.java:431)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.getWriteConcern(DatastoreImpl.java:1632)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.save(DatastoreImpl.java:686)`

`UserList` is a class that is not annotated with `@Entity` and has no `@Id` field, is that the reason?

Comment: That would be a different error.  What does UserList look like?